# Logging events from a remote machine

Tags: linux, ipc, snmp

I have a setup where a process logs the current of the outlet of a power distribution unit (it's a Schleifenbauer PDU and a gateway). It polls continuously the values and writes them to a file with the corresponding time stamps.

Now I want to launch different algorithms in a second machine (connected to the mentioned outlet) so I can measure the power consumption.

Since I have to write down the moments when the processes start and end, what would be a way to communicate these events with the SNMP manager, running in the first machine?

Sorry if the question is too naïf, and thanks for any help.

note: I am working with Linux in both machines.

Javier Ruiz

Answer (score 0):

After doing a little bit of homework, I simply measured time locally, executing remotely via ssh (I had to used public keys authorization). After the program ends in the remote machine I measure time again, and then extracts all the data that I need from the SNMP log.

Sorry for the stupid question...